# At which school levels do you learn to make games form scratch?

Tags: software-engineering, education

By which "school levels" I mean: high school, college etc....

---

So, I've just choose a high school in Sweden which has a game programming line.

I read some on their webpage and what you will learn there is Unity3D scripting. (and all other things, math, english, swedish etc)

My question is: At what "level" of school do you learn to make games from scratch?

And by school "level" I mean, do you learn it in high school, college  or something else?...

Does it maybe change depending on what school you go to?

Comment: I've started learned programming it in middle school. But the school itself certainly wasn't much help.

Comment: @Philipp At what age are you in middle-school where you live? In Sweden you cannot learn any programming at all in middle schools unless they are very different here... :P

Comment: What I was trying to tell you is: If you want to be a game developer, then don't rely on any education facility. Teach it to yourself. The internet is full of guides and tutorials.

Comment: @Philipp Yes, I already know how to build simple games from scratch in C++ but I want to know at which school "level" you "actually" learn this stuff. :P

Comment: I am a professional game programmer/designer with over 15 years industry experience. I have a master's degree in physics. You can learn this stuff on your own, as I have.

Comment: The school only teaches you basics and isn't much help.

Comment: There are very few 'schools' which will teach you something useful about gamedev. If you want to make games, learn stuff by yourself.

Comment: @BiiX, I don't think you'll find what you're looking for at school. The closest you'll get is by learning systems programming (compilers, OS, etc). Like everyone else is saying, your learn by programming games for yourself, and then by programming games for a job. Don't wait for classes, you'll just end up disappointed. Start building now. A great place to get started is with [Handmade Hero](https://hero.handmadedev.org/jace/guide/).

Comment: Using the language scratch (https://scratch.mit.edu/) and some guidance, I'm sure even kindergardeners could create something simple yet playable within hours.

Comment: @sarahm I know how to do some programming in C++, made a simple game, I just wanted to know :P

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to follow a game-programming programme to learn how to program games. It helps only on *some* aspects.

> Personal experience
>
> I've started to learn programming in high-school. We were free to chose the end-of-year project we had to do, and my friend and I decided to do a game. It was in VB6, the language we had learned the whole year.
>
> Then I studied computer science in college, then did a bachelor degree at university in computer science/software engineering. Then I got hired by a game development company and learned *a lot* while at work.

So to answer your question, *you can learn game development at **any** school level*. It depends on you, your motivation, and the school.

But my suggestion is: get a solid base in general programming *first*, then learn how to make games. Some school programmes will sacrifice crucial general programming concepts to make room for the game oriented stuff. You're better starting off with a solid base and transfer this knowledge to game dev, than jumping right away to the "cool stuff" but lacking some important concepts.

*And this is without saying that **some** schools just offer 'game dev' programmes just because it's cool and trendy, but in the end, they teach you bad concepts or just not enough of it and you end up paying the extra fee for bad quality teaching.*

P.S. You'll learn a lot by doing. Learn programming at school by day, and try to apply that by creating a game by night.

Comment: Yes, I do know how to make games from scratch, but i was just curious on which school levels most schools teach this. ^^

Comment: @BiiX Unfortunately, this really depends on _a lot_ of factors: country, province/territory/state, school + laws, regulations, religions, feelings and desire to make money. Basically, if your question involves a term such as "typically", or "generally", or "how are most others do", your question will be closed as off topic.